# Python websocket multiple message listeners

Tags: python, websocket, stream

I am using the Python Websocket library to connect and receive messages from a socket. The messages are received in the on_message function.

```
def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open,
                            on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()

def other_listener()
    request = {"method": "SUBSCRIBE","params":["param1"],"id": 1}
    result = ws.send(request)
    #also listen to the message received from websocket
```

I want the `other_listener` function to also receive the message from the websocket so it can get and work with the message of `param1` only so I can unsubscribe when I dont need the param one message. I have multiple `other_listener` functions so they can subscribe, use the message and unsubscribe from the stream.
I saw javascript has an `ws.add_event_listener(message, other_listener)` function
that does what I want. I cant find something similar in the python websocket docs. I have thought about making a global variable accessible to the other functions which I can add the messages as they are updated but that seems really hacky. Appreciate any insights.

Comment: you could run `other_listener()` inside `on_message()`

Comment: That is what I did. Had to change the whole architecture of the script but it works now. Thanks.